# Codechef practice problem - Chef and demonetisation

Tags: python, python-3.x

**THE QUESTION IS:**
In a country called Chef Land, there was a lot of monetary fraud, so Chefu, the head of the country, decided to choose new denominations of the local currency ― all even-valued coins up to an integer N should exist. After a few days, a citizen complained that there was no way to create an odd value, so Chefu decided that he should also introduce coins with value 1. Formally, you are given an integer N; for v=1 and each even positive integer v≤N, coins with value v exist.

You are also given an integer S. To handle transactions quickly, find the minimum number of coins needed to pay a price S.

Input
The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first and only line of each test case contains two space-separated integers S and N.
Output
For each test case, print a single line containing one integer ― the minimum number of coins.

**Constraints**
1≤T≤10,000
1≤S≤109
2≤N≤109
N is even

**Subtasks**
Subtask #1 (100 points): original constraints

**Example Input**
4
2 2
1 14
30 10
31 4
**Example Output**
1
1
3
9

**MY SOLUTION IS**

```
n=int(input())
res=[]
for i in range(1,n+1):
    S,N = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    rem=S%N
    if rem == 0:
        res.append(int(S/N))
    else:
        if rem==1:
            res.append(int(S/N+1))
        else:
            if rem/2 == 0:
                res.append(int(S/N+1))
            else:
                res.append(int(S/N+2))
for j in res:
    print(j)
```

**Its showing my answer is wrong. Can anyone help me ?**

Comment: Your answer is correct, in that it produces the appropriate output.  I suspect the site is looking for a string output rather than the list you are producing.  Change your print loop to a single output statement ```print(' '.join(res))```.

Comment: My mistake the print statement should be ```' '.join([str(x) for x in res])```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was not considering the case of getting 1 as a remainder i.e. in case of numbers like 31,41,51 etc. Which was causing me trouble. Well, after considering the above condition and some little manipulation it finally worked. Hope you understand it. And thank you for your responses.

```
n=int(input())
res=[]
for i in range(n):
    S,N = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    rem=S%N
    if S==1:
        res.append(int(1))
    elif(rem == 0):
        res.append(int(S/N))
    else:
        if(rem%2==0 or rem==1):
            res.append(int(S/N+1))
        else:
            res.append(int(S/N+2))
for j in res:
    print(j)
```